# Reorder Series Data Based on Month

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, series

I have a data frame with the following data:

```
month
April        4484.900000
August       5664.419355
December     3403.806452
February     2655.298246
January      2176.338710
July         5563.677419
June         5772.366667
March        3692.258065
May          5349.774194
November     4247.183333
October      5199.225806
September    5766.516667
```

I want the data to be ordered from January to December, not alphabetically. Is there a way to reorder this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) it based on the [`month_name`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) :

```
from calendar import month_name

out = s.reindex(month_name[1:]) # with `s` your Series
```

Output :

```
print(out)

month
January      2176.338710
February     2655.298246
March        3692.258065
April        4484.900000
May          5349.774194
June         5772.366667
July         5563.677419
August       5664.419355
September    5766.516667
October      5199.225806
November     4247.183333
December     3403.806452
dtype: float64
```

Used input :

```
s = pd.read_clipboard().squeeze().rename(None).rename_axis("month")
```